# Low Pass FIR Filter

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response

I want to design FIR low-pass filter with the following specifications:

```
 Cut-off frequency: 200 Hz 

  Order: 20 

  Sampling frequency: 1000 Hz
```

what should be the stepwise method to do so

Comment: Which software do you use? Or do you need to do this by hand? Note that your specs are very general and for this reason many methods are possible.

Comment: using matlab but not but in funtions

Comment: So you cannot use any functions of the Signal Processing Toolbox?

Comment: No, I cannot use any of the function from signal processing tool box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your filter is highly under-specified, so I assume that your design is supposed to be very basic. A very basic method would be to simply truncate and shift the impulse response of an ideal low pass filter with cutoff frequency $\omega_c=2\pi f_c/f_s=0.4\pi$ (where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency):

$$h_{ideal}(n)=\frac{\sin(\omega_c n)}{\pi n}$$

Note that since your filter must be causal you need to shift and truncate the ideal impulse response such that it is symmetric with respect to its maximum:

$$h(n)=\frac{\sin(\omega_c (n-10))}{\pi (n-10)},\quad n=0,1,\ldots,20\tag{1}$$

Equation (1) gives you the 21 filter coefficients $h(n)$ of a causal FIR filter approximating an ideal low pass filter response. Note that the filter order is 20.

A simple Matlab/Octave code could look like this:

```
n = -10:10;
omc = 0.4*pi;           % normalized cut-off frequency in rad
h = sin(omc*n)./(pi*n); % impulse response
h(11) = omc/pi;         % correct NaN value at n=0
H = fft(h,1024);        % complex frequency response
f = 1000/1024*(0:512);  % FFT frequency grid up to fs/2
plot(f,abs(H(1:513)));  % plot magnitude of frequency response
```

Comment: @farhan: You're welcome! If you feel that your question has been answered satisfactorily, you can accept it by hitting the 'accept' button next to the answer.

Comment: there are options of active and oldest no option of accept any where

Comment: can u help me if I wanted to draw a filter using rectangular window?

Comment: @farhan: There's a checkmark on the top left of the answer. What do you mean exactly by "draw a filter using rectangular window"? Make a plot of its frequency response?

Comment: Yes, I really want that code

Comment: The code in my answer makes a plot of the (magnitude of the) frequency response.

Comment: I still have one confusion ,  if you are there

Comment: @farhan: OK, just ask and I'll answer as soon as I have time to do so.

Comment: one thing is you have not plotted with x-axis in radian. Second you haven't used any of the window for example rectangular or hamming

Comment: @farhan: The plot is with frequency in Hz. If you want it in radians you just need to convert it to radians. Multiply the variable f in the plot command by $2\pi/1000$ and you're done. And of course I've used a window to design the filter. Truncation is equivalent to using a rectangular window.

Comment: okay one last question, what If I wanted to use hamming window

Comment: Then you need to multiply the ideal impulse response (the sinc function) with a hamming window.

Comment: I cant see ripples using hamming window

Comment: I used that code for hamming
   M=21;
    hamming_window=hamming(M);
    n = -10:10;
    omc = 0.4*pi;         
    h = sin(omc*n)./(pi*n); 
    h(11) = omc/pi;           
    FIR_lp = h.*hamming_window';
    H4=fft(FIR_lp, 1024);
    f = 1000/1024*(0:512);
    plot(f*(2*pi/1000),abs(H4(1:513)));

Comment: @farhan: You do have ripples, you just don't see them on a linear scale. Plot in dB: 20*log10(abs(H4)), then you'll see that there are ripples, but they are much lower than the ones of the other filter. Note, however, that the transition band is much wider now.