# Attenuate the low frequencies in a speech wave

Tags: audio, python, finite-impulse-response, highpass-filter, audio-processing

I am designing an `FIR` filter to attenuate the frequencies below `300Hz`. I designed the filter using the `scipy` functions and the code is as below.

```
from numpy import cos, sin, pi, absolute, arange
from scipy.signal import kaiserord, lfilter, firwin, freqz
from pylab import figure, clf, plot, xlabel, ylabel, xlim, ylim, title, grid, 
axes, show

nyq_rate = 48000 / 2
width = 100 / nyq_rate
ripple_db = 60.0
cutoff_hz = 300.0

N, beta = kaiserord(ripple_db, width)
taps = firwin(N, cutoff_hz/nyq_rate, window=('kaiser', beta), pass_zero='highpass')
w, h = freqz(taps, worN=512)

plot((w/pi)*nyq_rate, absolute(h), linewidth=2)
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Gain')
title('Frequency Response')
ylim(-0.05, 1.05)
grid(True)

show()
```

When I a execute it, the following error pops up.

```
ValueError: A filter with an even number of coefficients must have zero response at the Nyquist frequency.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Okay. I think the error is using even number of filter coefficients. Adding 1 to `N` gets rid of the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Low Pass FIR Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15902/low-pass-fir-filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already figured out, you need to choose an odd filter length. I'll explain why. You're designing a linear phase FIR filter, and such filters satisfy certain symmetry conditions. See [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9413/4298) explaining the four types of linear phase FIR filters (even/odd length, even/odd symmetry).

For frequency selective filters, such as the one you're trying to design, you need filters with even symmetry (type I or type II). An even length (type II) filter necessarily has a zero at Nyquist, so you can't use it to design a high pass filter. A type I filter (even symmetry, odd filter length) doesn't have this restriction, so in order to design a linear phase high pass filter you need to choose an odd filter length, i.e., a type I linear phase FIR filter.

Comment: How can I pass the attenuation factor for stop band as an input while deisgning filter in `Python`? In the scipy provided functions like `kaiserord`, there is an argument called `ripple`. But after assigining that argument to 12 dB I don't see the relative change in the frequency response.

Comment: @Dennis.M: I don't use Python, but I think I know what ´kaiserord´ is doing. You should try a higher value for 'ripple', maybe 60 dB.